# .NET Premitive Types with C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

Previously in my .Net C# API project, I was using GUID data types & now I have created .Net Primitive types.

I have changed all DTOs/Models data types & written down JsonConverter class as a property field attribute so it should be compatible with my previous response & request type. Similarly, I have written SqlMapper for my Dapper SQL library.

So now, my problem is when I inserting data into MongoDB using Mongo DB driver(InsertOneAsync) it is inserting as

[image]

and when I am trying to get data using FindAsync, it is giving an error like "An error occurred while deserializing the TenantId property of class DemoProject.Common.Shared.DocumentDb.Modeling.DocumentBase: Value class PrimitivesProject.TenantId cannot be deserialized"

**So my question is, Do I need to write any TypeConverter or Need write some serialize/deserialization options while insert/retrieving data into Mongo DB?

or Please suggest if there are any other options**

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: So what C# type is your `TenantId`? A `byte[]`?

Comment: @CodeCaster - TenantId has type GUID

Comment: have you marked your Id as [BsonId] ??

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi - No, I haven't mark TenantId as BsonId, I am relatively new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a BSON serialization class. Used that class as an attribute of Model/DTO property. (like  [BsonSerializer(typeof(TenantIdSerializer))] ).

Below is a reference link for the same. Please change the version accordingly. I have 2.8 driver version.
[Bson Serialization](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/serialization/)